POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sparepart 404 (Not Found) when i try to Inertia.post('/admin/sparepart', formData)
I use Laravel, Inertia and Vue.
When I submitted the form, the page returned a 404 not found window and the console said
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sparepart 404 (Not Found)
I don't know if it's because of an error in the route or if the form wasn't sent correctly to the backend.
This is from the network header tabs:
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sparepart
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

In the payload, it seems the formData does exist:
nama_sparepart: as
harga: 2
stok: 2
kategori_id: 1
image: (binary)

I'm using Route::resource
Route::resource('/admin/sparepart', SparepartController::class);
and yeah it does exist when I use route::list

GET|HEAD        admin/sparepart ....................................... sparepart.index › SparepartController@index
POST            admin/sparepart ....................................... sparepart.store › SparepartController@store

controller:
public function store(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'nama_sparepart' => 'required|string|max: 25',
            'harga' => 'required|number',
            'stok' => 'required|number',
            'image' => 'required|image',
            'kategori_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image->storeAs('public/spareparts', $image->hashname());

        $sparepart = Sparepart::create([
            'nama_sparepart' => $request->nama_sparepart,
            'harga' => $request->harga,
            'stok' => $request->stok,
            'image' => $image->hashName(),
            'kategori_id' => $request->kategori_id,
        ]);

        if($sparepart){
            return Redirect::route('sparepart.index')->with('message', 'success');
        }

Vue scripts
<script setup>
    import { reactive } from 'vue'
    import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia'

        //props
        defineProps({
            errors: Object,
            kategori: Array
        })

            //state posts
            const sparepart = reactive({
                nama_sparepart  : '',
                harga           : '',
                stok            : '',
                image           : null,
                kategori_id     : ''
            })

            function handleImageUpload(event) {
                const file = event.target.files[0]
                 console.log("File yang dipilih:", file);
                if (file) {
                    sparepart.image = file // Simpan file ke state
                }
            }

         //function storePost
function storePost() {
    console.log("State sebelum dikirim:", sparepart);
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('nama_sparepart', sparepart.nama_sparepart)
    formData.append('harga', sparepart.harga)
    formData.append('stok', sparepart.stok)
    formData.append('kategori_id', sparepart.kategori_id)
    if (sparepart.image) {
        formData.append('image', sparepart.image) // Sertakan file gambar
    }


    // Debugging FormData
    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    }

    // Kirim data dengan FormData
    Inertia.post('/admin/sparepart', formData)

}
</script>

Vue page:
<template>
     <div>
        <div class="card border-0 rounded shadow">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4>TAMBAH POST</h4>
                <hr>
                <form @submit.prevent="storePost" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div>
                        <label for="image">Gambar</label>
                        <input type="file" id="image" @change="handleImageUpload" accept="image/*" />
                        <span v-if="errors.image">{{ errors.image }}</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Nama Sparepart</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="sparepart.nama_sparepart" placeholder="Masukkan Title Post">
                        <div v-if="errors.nama_sparepart" class="mt-2 alert alert-danger">
                            {{ errors.nama_sparepart }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Harga</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="sparepart.harga" placeholder="Masukkan Title Post">
                        <div v-if="errors.harga" class="mt-2 alert alert-danger">
                            {{ errors.harga }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Stok</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="sparepart.stok" placeholder="Masukkan Title Post">
                        <div v-if="errors.stok" class="mt-2 alert alert-danger">
                            {{ errors.stok }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="kategori_id">Kategori</label>
                        <select v-model="sparepart.kategori_id" id="kategori_id">
                            <option value="">Pilih Kategori</option>
                            <option v-for="k in kategori" :key="k.id" :value="k.id">{{ k.nama_kategori }}</option>
                        </select>
                        <span v-if="errors.kategori_id">{{ errors.kategori_id }}</span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Tombol Submit -->
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

I tried to do a manual route(like Route::post('url',[controller class])), but I still get a 404.

Did you clear the route cache after adding the route? php artisan route:clear ?

yes i do, and i tried it again just before. still same result

i changed the routes from
Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {

Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/admin/admin-control', [AdminController::class, 'showAdmin'])->name('admin.show');
Route::get('/admin/create', [AdminController::class, 'addAdmin'])->name('admin.create');
Route::post('/admin/create', [AdminController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.createSubmit');
Route::get('/admin/{id}/edit', [AdminController::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.edit');
Route::post('/admin/edit', [AdminController::class, 'update'])->name('admin.update');
Route::post('/admin/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'destroy'])->name('admin.delete');

/*-------------Sparepart-------------- */
Route::resource('/admin/sparepart', SparepartController::class);
/*-----------End sparepart-------------- */

});
to
Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {

Route::resource('/admin/sparepart', SparepartController::class);

Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/admin/admin-control', [AdminController::class, 'showAdmin'])->name('admin.show');
Route::get('/admin/create', [AdminController::class, 'addAdmin'])->name('admin.create');
Route::post('/admin/create', [AdminController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.createSubmit');
Route::get('/admin/{id}/edit', [AdminController::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.edit');
Route::post('/admin/edit', [AdminController::class, 'update'])->name('admin.update');
Route::post('/admin/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'destroy'])->name('admin.delete');

});

Run php artisan route:list first to confirm that your code can see the route. If it exists, it could be a laravel route cache issue. Run the following commands to clear the cache:
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear


as i stated above, the route is exist when i check route:list
already tried to clear all cache, config,etc and still same

i prefer using axios when sending a request, instead using Inertia request
and try use this headers at your request
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}

i've same problem too when i'm using laravel inertia react, it's little bit tricky i guess and it's work for me.
Hope it gonna help your problem

The point of using Inertia is that you don't need to do stuff like axios requests.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
